# Which form is better to use for map

Tags: c++

Given a class `Ac` and a map:

```
std::map<std::string, Ac> ma;
```

Which of the following forms is better:

```
ma["112"] = Ac(); // (1)
```

or

```
Ac ac;
ma["112"] = ac;   // (2)
```

Is there any issue using the version 1?

The actual code in context:

```
struct Ac
{
    bool first;
    bool second;
};

int main()
{   
    std::map<std::string, Ac> ma;
    std::string st = "10.12";
    if (ma.find(st) == ma.end())
    {   
#if 0
        // 1
        ma["112"] = Ac();
#else            
        // 2
        Ac ac;
        ma["112"] = ac;
#endif
    }
    else
        ma[st].first = true;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: They don't express the same thing. in #2, `ac` still exists and is usable after insterting a *copy* of it in the map.

Comment: it depends what you need and what you want to do. You could also insert an element via `ma["112"];` as well. Consider `insert` or `emplace` when the actual aim is to insert an element in the map.

Comment: my aim is to insert in map and use only the struct from the map  afterward.

Comment: In such a simple case the compiler very likely oprimizes the second version to work the same as the first one. the one issue I see with both versions is that the member variables of the object are uninitialized.

Comment: `Ac &ac = ma["112"];`

Comment: @Frank before this operation I would check whether elemenet for given key exist or not, if not I would insert a new element

Comment: In that case, you should use [std::map::emplace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace), which does all of this at once. (edit, noticed the c++14 tag, so recommended a compatible method)

Comment: First or second what?  The lines marked "2" are comments- they do nothing.

Comment: do you really want to leave members uninitialized? If `first` should be set to true in both cases you can replace most of the code with only `ma[st].first = true;`. `operator[]` does find the element *and* returns a reference to it (and if it does not find it, it inserts a default constructed one)

Comment: @Clifford that's my question, which form to use ?

Comment: Yes but you should post it as two real code fragments, not as comments.  It is slightly pedantic, but there is a lot of redundancy in this question.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number can I use default initializer list for false while inserting new element in the map ? it will always find it since before I check if it is already in map or not.

Comment: Prefer #1, it's simpler. Besides, with optimizations enabled, the compiler will transform #2 into #1 anyways.

Comment: @BenRice  I changed your question considerably to make it (IMO) clearer.  Feel free to roll it back if you disagree or if I have materially changed what you are asking.  The important thing was not to post a comment and ask if it was better that actual code, and also to focus on the issue without wading through the surrounding code - though I have retained that for context - removing it would have been too much of a liberty if it is not already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you do not want to leave the members uninitialized, so lets supply default initializers:

```
struct Ac
{
    bool first = false;
    bool second = false;
};
```

Next, you are looking up the key too often. First you call `find` and when the element was found you call `operator[]` which has to find the element again. Instead use the iterator returned from `find`.

Concerning your question, the most obvious difference is that one version adds a copy of a temporary while the other inserts a copy of a local variable. If you do not need the local variable, you can call `emplace` to construct the element in place:

```
int main()
{   
    std::map<std::string, Ac> ma;
    std::string st = "10.12";
    auto ret = ma.emplace(st,Ac{});
    if (! ret.second)
    {   
        ret.first->second.first = true;
    }
}
```

`emplace` (similar to `insert`) returns a `pair` of `bool` to indicate whether insertion took place and an iterator to the element. `ret.first->second.first` can be a little confusing. `ret.first` is the iterator to the element in the map `ret.first->second` is the `Ac` part of that element and `ret.first->second.first` is its `first` member.

After compiler optimizations this is probably just as efficient as either of your two versions, but I consider it more clear to use `emplace` when you want to insert an element, and because construction of an `Ac` is comparatively cheap, it is also not too bad to contruct the temporary anyhow without checking the map before. To be really sure what performs better you would need to measure it. In general, `std::unordered_map` can be expected to be faster, because its elements are not sorted with respect to the keys.

Comment: thanks for your answer, if  ma.emplace(st,Ac{}); is used with default initializer list, is still needed to add bool first = false; values mannualy for struct members, wouldn't be that done by the defualt initializer list when inserting in into map ?

Comment: @BenRice what "default initializer list"? Sorry I dont understand what you mean. In your code the members are not initialized when the element wasnt already in the map before

Comment: if i simply insert in map only when element for given key was not found with ma.emplace(st,Ac{}); would not suffice ? I mean this way Ac elements will be initialized

Comment: @BenRice from your comment ("can I use default initializer list for false while inserting new element in the map ?") I assumed the newly created element should have the member set to `false`. If you want `true` in both cases then only `emplace` is sufficient. Though in your code the members of `Ac` are not initialized (also not if you use `emplace(st,Ac{})`)

Comment: if I'm using emplace(st,Ac{}) why are not initialized ? I would do like to have them set to false.

Comment: @BenRice it might be zero-initialized, not sure. Initialization is a difficult topic. I would just provide a default initializer as suggested in the answer

Comment: btw why would zero-initilized values be problematic ?

Comment: @BenRice I didn't say that is would be problematic, I am just not sure if they are zero-initialized.

Comment: The two lookups are wanted, there are different keys used for the `find` and `[]`

Comment: @Caleth oh right. I admit, I didnt fully understand the question when I wrote this, and there are more reasons why I dont like the answer. If it wasnt accepted I would delete it. Maybe I'll fix it later

Answer (score 1):

In (2) the object `ac` exists to the end of the scope, whereas (1) creates a temporary that is immediacy discarded when it is no longer needed.

It also provides no symbol or reference by which you might access the temporary; you can *only* access the object created in the `map` itself which is your stated aim.

So it is not really a matter of "*better*" but rather which is most appropriate in the particularly situation since they are not semantically equivalent.  In this case (1), however if you wanted to create an object, perform some operations on it *before* placing it in the map, then (2) would be *required*.

If you performed operations on it *after copying* it to the map, then clearly those changes would be on the object not the copy in the map.

Comment: Thank you @Clifford